# add system user without login but able to su without asking for password

Tags: rhel6, useradd

I created a user "sysuser" with -r option, when trying to su using another non-root user I am prompted for password.

As "sysuser" is a system account and should not login, I did not set up a password. (With sysuser I need to be able to own files and run tomcat.)

What can I do to su without password prompt?  The OS is RHEL 6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113754/allow-user1-to-su-user2-without-password

Comment: @oldskool, yes they look similar but I have tried the solution..doesnt work. Possibly the user I am trying to setup is system account?

Comment: 'code' auth       [success=ignore default=1] pam_succeed_if.so user = martin-test
auth       sufficient   pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user = martin                        'code' Actually tried with 2 normal users too...still being prompted for password when su.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of experimenting I solved my own problem. Requirement was for ANY USER to be able to su to sysuser without password prompt. Added the below line /etc/pam.d/su:

```
auth sufficient pam_succeed_if.so user = sysuser
```